# re.compile SQL Query in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm attempting to run a mysql query using python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mysql.connector
import re

db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='planes',user='root',password='root')


cursor = db.cursor ( )


cursor.execute("SELECT * from acars where date_time_stamp between str_to_date('2016-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d') "
               "and str_to_date('2016-09-30', '%Y-%m-%d')")



# Fetch rows
data = cursor.fetchall()

for row in data:
    print row

p = re.compile('K[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]')
str =
print(p.findall(row))


# close cursor
cursor.close ( )

# close connection
db.close ( )
```

My problem begins in the section with the "Fetch Rows" comment. I'd like to run the re.compile to search each returned data entry for instances that 4-letter strings beginning with 'K' appear. I cannot figure out what to use as the str to represent my returned data though.

Comment: Your row is not a astring, it is a tuple of each column's value.

Comment: well row is going to be a list here, so you can't really apply a regex on it. Am I wrong to assume there is a specific column in your database which would contain those 4-letter strings? If yes you can filter in the query inself. If you absolutely want to do it in python, then target that specific column in each row

Comment: Please show what data is returned b query. You use `*` in SQL which anonymizes columns of 1 or 100.